# svn error: .plist file has inconsistent newlines additional errors

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I am trying to commit my xcode project it says that myplist.plist inconsistent newlines additional errors in svn.

Please give your suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the smartSVN to commit your code or command-line? Originally I got the same error as you by using SmartSVN, then choose command-line and it works.

svn commit - m "message to commit"

Comment: I was using smartSVN and faced this issue later fixed it with command line `svn commit - m "message to commit"`